# modelio does not import overture uml exported file

Tags: uml, modelio, vdm++

I want to learn how to use Modelio and Overture together to learn to model programs with UML and VDM. The whole procedure about creating a UML model, exporting it to XMI (uml extension), and importing to Overture is done successfully.

However, when I try to export it back to Modelio, it brings "Failed: file content is not recognized as a valid model". Overture's tutorial tells it's possible to import/export back and forth; however, it seems the feature is broken as of now.

I may be doing something wrong. Maybe I have to set Overture in a certain way for Modelio to understand its exported XMI file. All of my online searches for a solution have been unsuccessful. How may I successfully export/import from Overture to Modelio?

I'm using Modelio 3.4.1 and Overture 2.3.0.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you add the XMI file to your question?

Comment: @Red It seems there is no way to upload it, so I'm copy/pasting it here... No, that doesn't work either, too long. Sorry, I'm not used to this site yet. How may I add it?

Comment: I uploaded it to a file hosting service. You may download it from http://sabercathost.com/7iI/Roulette.uml

Comment: @RedBeard A few days have passed. I've been assuming you might be figuring out what's wrong. Anything?

Comment: In fact it seems to be an issue with the 3.4.1 version of Modelio. I was able to import your model with Modelio 3.3.1.

Comment: Thank you very much! I went to Modelio.org, downloaded version 3.3.1, and successfully imported Overture's exported file.

Comment: This is being tracked by an Overture bug now, though it looks like this is just a version compatibility issue: https://github.com/overturetool/overture/issues/509

Comment: This is now fixed with latest Modelio version i.e. 3.5